# Integration of complex numbers using trapezoidal rule in C++

Tags: c++, numerical-integration

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

complex<double> integral(complex<double> (*f)(complex<double> const &x), complex<double> l, complex<double> u, size_t n) 
{
    complex<double> step = (u - l) / (double) n;
    complex<double> area(0, 0);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        complex<double> inner = l + (i + 0.5) * step;
        area = area + f(inner) / inner * step;
    }
    return area;
}
int main() 
{
    complex<double> l(0, 0);
    complex<double> u(2, 1);
    cout << integral(cos, l, u, 100);
}
```

I get the this output (5.77123,-0.761154)

The integral of this function is sin(i+2)=(1.403-0.489i) [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%20cos%28x%29%20from%20%280%2B0i%29%20to%20%282%2Bi%29)

I do not know what could be the problem.

Comment: Why the `/ inner`?

Comment: if I use area = area + f(inner) * step; it is working,

Comment: @taiwan12 it's not a trapezoidal rule, it's rectangular rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was commented, dividing by `inner` was an extraneous step.

```
complex<double> integral(complex<double> (*f)(complex<double> const &x), complex<double> l, complex<double> u, size_t n) 
{
    complex<double> step = (u - l) / (double) n;
    complex<double> area(0, 0);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        complex<double> inner = l + (i + 0.5) * step;
        area += f(inner) * step;
    }
    return area;
}
```

[See live](https://godbolt.org/z/86hdE7)